# __restrict in g++ and MSVC with Array Syntax

Tags: c++, restrict, restrict-qualifier

I'm in the process of updating performance critical libraries to use `restrict`, as implemented in C++11 by g++ and MSVC with the keyword `__restrict`.

There are a lot of routines and functions that look something like:

```
void f(float a[],float b[]);
```

In the above example, `f` is a routine whose arguments should be restricted.  Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, this is impossible while maintaining that syntax.  Now, clearly this can be rewritten using pointers as:

```
void f(float*__restrict a,float*__restrict b);
```

What got lost here is the semantic fact that `a` and `b` are arrays (I prefer using pointer notation for single-value pointers and array notation for array pointers).  Descriptive argument names (omitted above) help, but only so much.

I would like to confirm that declaring restricted variables using array syntax is impossible for these compilers at this time.

Comment: You may still use `using float_array = float[];` and then `void f(float_array __restrict a, float_array __restrict b);`

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks for that; too unwieldy for my taste, unfortunately.